# How to modify the ostream object to create ideal cout?

Tags: c++11, iostream, cout

I am using c++11 currently and I am working on a friend function to print out sth, but before calling the print function I need to call a member function inside the class to access and serialize the two data member. I am having a problem modifying the ostream object.
The code is as below:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Card& c) {
     c.serialize(os);
     return os;}

void NumberCard:: serialize(ostream& os) const
 {
 Color c=this->getColor();
 switch(c){
  case Color::red:  os=(os<<"R"<<this->getPoint());break;
  case Color::yellow: os=(os<<"Y"<<this->getPoint());break;
  case Color::blue: os=(os<<"B"<<this->getPoint());break;
  case Color::green: os=(os<<"G"<<this->getPoint());break;   
  default:break;}}
```

My current method doesn't work and the error is:

```
use of deleted function 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator=(const std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]'
```

It would be really appreciated if someone could give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
os=(os<<"R"<<this->getPoint());
```

That is a problem since assignment to an `ostream` object is not supported by the standard library.

Use

```
os << "R" << this->getPoint();
```

Answer (score 0):

`ostream& os` is a reference to an `ostream`. A C++ reference to an object is supposed to be indistinguishable from the actual object in terms of how it is used. This means that a reference cannot be reassigned -- rather, the object being referenced gets assigned to instead of the reference variable itself.

`ostream` is declared with a deleted copy-assignment operator, because you cannot copy a stream (this makes sense).

Combining these together, you'll understand that `os = ...` is causing the assignment operator to be called, which results in that error.

As it turns out, there's no need to reassign to `os`, since the reference returned by `<<` is to the same (mutated) `ostream` object in the first place (this is done so that `<<` calls can be chained).

Your switch code then simplifies to:

```
case Color::red:    os << "R" << this->getPoint(); break;
case Color::yellow: os << "Y" << this->getPoint(); break;
// ...
```

Comment: The error is solely due to the deleted assignment operator. In the OP's usage, it is unrelated to the fact that the copy constructor is also deleted.

Comment: Your explanation is quite clear to me and thanks for reminding me that operator<< could works.